# Почему не работает execl()?

Tags: android, linux, c, boot, initramfs

Решился на необычный эксперимент:

```
 ~ # unmkbootimg -i boot.img
 ~ # mkdir ramdisk
 ~ # gzip -kdc initrd.gz | cpio -i -D ramdisk
 ~ # cd ramdisk
 ~/ramdisk # ls -a
.       apex          init      proc
..      debug_ramdisk mnt       sys
.backup dev           overlay.d
 ~/ramdisk # mv init magiskinit
 ~/ramdisk # gcc ../init.c -static -o init
 ~/ramdisk # find ./* | cpio -H newc -o | gzip -c > ../initrd.gz-new
 ~/ramdisk # cd ..
 ~ # mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk initrd.gz-new -o newboot.img
 ~ # dd if=newboot.img of=/dev/block/by-name/boot
```

Код `init.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    execl("/magiskinit", "/magiskinit", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Перезагружаю - и тут странность. С одной стороны, init вроде бы стартует (если бы не стартовал, сразу улетел бы в fastboot с kernel panic). С другой - то ли он не может передать управление magiskinit, то ли самому magiskinit что-то не нравится, но телефон перезагружается через 3-5 секунд... *[И да, execl с init-а вполне возможен, magiskinit именно так запускает оригинальный init]*. А отследить никак, ядро не поддерживает ни LLCON, ни FBCON, а оборудования для работы с UART у меня нету... **/sys/fs/pstore** молчит.

По идее, делов-то - просто передать управление init-у, можно сравнить со switch_root. Что я делаю не так, может предварительно смонтировать /proc, /sys, /dev, /sys/fs/selinux?

И сразу отвечу на вопрос: зачем? Вообще, я хотел бы получить список файлов в /dev, /sys, /proc в ramdisk-е, на этапе, когда эти три раздела смонтированы, но ещё не сделан switch_root, не модифицирована политика SELinux и не сделан 'magic mount' от Magisk-а. А получать я собрался очень просто - пройтись рекурсивно по трём директориям, и записать содержимое в файл в /dev (туда все равно монтируется обычная tmpfs, так можно было бы записать, а затем просто забрать из запущенной системы).

Девайс - Android 10, system-as-root (Legacy SAR).

Comment: менял execl на execve... Толку ноль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: оказалось, надо переименовать magiskinit в init, и вызывать его с этим именем...

Comment: можно не переименовывать, но вызывать с именем init. magiskinit похоже простой бизибокс

Comment: как раз нет, чекайте исходники!!! magiskinit патчит SELinux, прокидывает magic mount, прокидывает /sbin/su